# TFS Licensing and CALs with SharePoint

Tags: tfs, licensing

TFS creates a SharePoint site that has some dashboard information (burn rate and bug reports).

The CAL says: "Hardware and software that reduce the number of users or devices that directly access Team Foundation Server (sometimes referred to as “multiplexing” or “pooling”) do not reduce the number of Team Foundation Server CALs that are required. End users or devices that access Team Foundation Server in any way−other than the When a Client License is not Required scenarios noted above−are required to have the appropriate licenses, regardless of whether they are using a direct or indirect connection to the software." (from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350)

So, does that mean that anyone that accesses the SharePoint site needs a CAL?

**Edit** I guess the gist of the question is: Does the CAL exception scenario "Accessing Team Foundation Server reports" (from *When a Client License is not Required*) include the SharePoint plugins, or is it just the reports generated from SQL Server Reporting Services?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: I'm fine with that -- had programmers.stackexchange.com been available at the time the question was added, I would have asked there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a TFS CAL for viewing reports in TFS.

Source: [Brian Harry's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/08/even-better-access-to-team-foundation-server.aspx).

> We have removed the TFS CAL requirement (you still need whatever
>   Sharepoint/Office licensing is appropriate) for viewing reports in
>   TFS.  This addresses a long standing concern that it was not
>   reasonable to require a CAL for the occasional stakeholder who wanted
>   to check a report to see progress or issues.  Add this to the Work
>   Item Only View CAL exemption that we added a couple of years ago and
>   you get a pretty comprehensive solution for the occasional, loosely
>   connected stakeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need a CAL if you log on the SharePoint site that displays: Work Item queries results, backlogs, SQL Reports of TFS generated data, Excel services reports of TFS generated data and so on...

You don't need a CAL for the Work Item Web Access site, that's all...